# Android Authenticating from SQL Database

Tags: android, sql

```
public class SignIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button SignInbtn;
    EditText Email,Password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_screen);

        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

        SignInbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        SignInbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btnSignIn:
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try{
            String email = Email.getText().toString();
            String password = Password.getText().toString();
            PackageITDB SignIn = new PackageITDB(this);
            SignIn.open();
            String verifyEmail = SignIn.verifyEmail(email);
            String verifyPassword = SignIn.verifyPassword(password);
            SignIn.close();
            if(verifyEmail == email && verifyPassword == password){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this,UpdateProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this,SQLiteExample.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            }catch (Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Dang it!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

            }finally{
                if(didItWork){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Heck Yea!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is my activity class, it is suppose to get an email and a password, den will authenticate with the sqldatabase and then go to the updateprofile class, but I do not know why when I enter the email and password that is in the database, it still goes to the SQLiteExample class.

```
public String verifyEmail(String email) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String results;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            results = c.getString(1);
            if (results == email)
                return results;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String verifyPassword(String password) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String results;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            results = c.getString(3);
            if (results == password)
                return results;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my code for the database class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public boolean verifyEmail(String email) throws SQLException {
            ...
            results = c.getString(1);
            if (results != null && results.equals(email))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean verifyPassword(String password) throws SQLException {
            ....
            results = c.getString(3);
            if (results != null && results.equals(password))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


  public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        SignIn.open();
        boolean verifyEmail = SignIn.verifyEmail(email);
        boolean verifyPassword = SignIn.verifyPassword(password);
        SignIn.close();
        if(verifyEmail && verifyPassword) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this,UpdateProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
       ...
```

By the way, are you sure you close your connection properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings in-correctly. You have to compare it this way

```
if( verifyEmail.equals(email) && verifyPassword.equals(password) )
```

**EDIT:**
 You are pretty new to java? You are doing a wrong string comparison everywhere.
 In methods `verifyPassword` and `verifyEmail` you are comparing strings using `==` while you should do it via `equals` method. 
Change `if (results == email)` to `if (results.equals(email))` and `if(results == password)` to `if(results.equals(password)`. Also both methods returns `null`  when no match found so it would obviously make a `null pointer` exception in `onClick` method. You should consider returning a boolean and based on the boolean you should start the appropiate Intent :-/

Comment: now i change to this code, it gives me and error, it doesnt even go to any other class